# Pywedge_Charts issue in latest pandas

Tags: pandas, visualization, dashboard, jupyter-lab

`TypeError   1 mc = pw.Pywedge_Charts(df,c=None, y="Global_Sales")`

/* Error in latest pandas */
`TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.